# Why neo4j don't allows not directed or bidirectional relationships at creation time?

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I know that Neo4j requires a relationship direction at creation time, but allows ignore this direction in query time. By this way I can query my graph ignoring the relationship direction.

I also know that there are some workarounds for cases when the relationships are naturally bidirectional or not directed, [like described here](https://graphaware.com/neo4j/2013/10/11/neo4j-bidirectional-relationships.html).

**My question is:** Why is it implemented that way? Has a good reason to not allow not directed or bidirectional relationships at creation time? Is it a limitation of the database architecture?

The Cypher statements like below are not allowed:

```
CREATE ()-[:KNOWS]-()
CREATE ()<-[:KNOWS]->()
```

I searched the web for an answer, but I did not find much. For example, [this github issue](https://github.com/neo4j/neo4j/issues/1341).

Is strange to have to define a relationship direction to one that don't have it. It seems to me that i'm hurting the semantic of my graph.

**EDIT 1:**

To clarify my standpoint about a "semantic problem" (maybe the term is wrong):

Suppose that I run this simple `CREATE` statement:

```
CREATE (a:Person {name:'a'})-[:KNOWS]->(b:Person {name:'b'})
```

As result i have this very simple graph:

[image: Simple graph]

The `:KNOWS` relationship has a direction only because Neo4j requires a relationship direction at creation time. In my domain `a` knows `b` and `b` knows `a`.

Now, a new team member will query my graph with this Cypher query:

```
MATCH path = (a:Person {name:'a'})-[:KNOWS]-(b:Person {name:'b'})
return path
```

This new team member don't know that when I created this graph I considered that `:KNOWS` relationship is not directed. The result that he will see is the same:

[image: Simple graph]

By the result this new team member can think that only Person a consider knows Person b. It seems to me bad. Not for you? This make any sense?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Fundamentally, it boils down to the internals of how the data is stored on disk in Neo4j -- note Chapter 6 of the O'Reilly Neo4j e-book.

In the data structure of a relationship they have a "firstNode" and a "secondNode", where each is either the left or the right hand side of the relationship.

To flag a relationship as uni/bi-directional would require an additional bit per node, where I would argue it is better to retain the direction in the data store and just ignore direction during querying.

Comment: Hello @kuah! Your answer is very close to what I expect. I'm reading this book and will read the recommended chapter in a near future! Thanks! :)

Answer (score 2):

In Neo4j relationships are always directed.

But if you don't care about the direction, you can ignore the direction when querying.

```
MATCH (p1:Person {name:"me"})-[:KNOWS]-(p2)
RETURN p2;
```

And with MERGE you can also leave off the direction when creating.

```
MATCH (p1:Person {name:"me"})
MATCH (p2:Person {name:"you"})
MERGE (p1)-[:KNOWS]-(p2);
```

You only need 2 relationships if they really convey a different meaning, e.g. `:FOLLOWS` on Twitter.

Comment: Hello @Michael Hunger. Thanks for your answer! Yes, I understood that at query time the relationships can be ignored. However my question is more about "why" Neo4j requires a direction at create time, as answered by kwah.

Comment: actually I tried this syntax but it seems the graph is created with a direction anyway, or at least that's how the neo4j explorer displays it.

Answer (score 0):

> It seems to me that i'm hurting the semantic of my graph.

I can't see why a `<` or `>` symbol used during creation of a relationship hurts the semantics of your graph if you are going to not use that symbol during matching (and thus treating that relationship as undirected/bidirectional).

Suppose that the syntax proposed by you is supported. Now how will you connect with an undirected relationship two nodes **a** and **b**? You still have two options:

1. `CREATE (a)-[:KNOWS]-(b)`
2. `CREATE (b)-[:KNOWS]-(a)`

The pair `(a, b)` is always ordered by appearance even if not by semantics. So even if we remove the `<` or `>` symbol from the relationship declaration, the problem with the order of nodes in it cannot be eliminated. Therefore simply don't treat it is a problem.

Comment: Hi @Leon! I edited my question trying to clarify my standpoint about this! Thanks for your time!